# jQuery: select first-child input inside form but not when type:hidden?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I have a variable that hold different form-objects like this … `$(formId)`

Each form is different as in either has an hidden input field as first element or the first-child is a normal input (type="text" or something else)

how can I ALWAYS select the the first "normal" input field

```
$(formId).find("input:first-child:not[type='hidden']")
```

I thought it should be something like this. So if you wonder what I need this for - I want to set the focus to the first input field in the form, but if the first input is a hidden one I of course want to set it to the next "visible" input.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector selects an element which **is the first child**, ***not*** the first item in a jQuery collection.
To select the first element of a collection, use jQuery's [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector.

Your implementation of [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is also wrong.
`:not[type='hidden']` **is equal to** `:not()[type='hidden']` **is equal to** `[type='hidden']` - The **opposite** of what you want.

---

These are the right selectors (they're equivalent):

```
input:not([type=hidden]):first
input[type!=hidden]:first
```

Answer (score 8):

`$(formId).find ('input:visible:first').focus();`

Comment: `:visible` is not equal to `[type!="hidden"]`. If you add `style="display:none"` to an input element, it **does not** `:visible`, but it **does** match `[type!="hidden"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Would using the :hidden selector work in your case ?

```
$(formId).find("input:first-child:not(:hidden)")
```

(Not so sure I get what your markup looks like...)

Comment: The `:first-child` selector selects an element which is the first child. To select the first element of a collection, use jQuery's `:first` selector: `input:not([type=hidden]):first`.

Comment: @Rob W: this seems to work perfect and looks like the right solution. If you post it as answer I'll accept it.